# OpenCV finds only image border as contour

Tags: java, opencv

I want to get all the outer contours with `RETR_EXTERNAL` but for some weird reason openCV thinks that the image border is a contour too and therefore discards all inner contours. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(imageA, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                     Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    double[] c = hierarchy.get(0, i);
    Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
    Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
        new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), 
        new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
}
```

**Input (imageA was processed to this before contour-finding):**

[image: Input imageA]

**Output:**

[image: Output of this code]

**EDIT:**
**Problem partially solved**
Inverting the pixels so that black is the background and white the foreground helped with the image above image. However I still get inner contours on some images. Like this one:

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Input image should be Cv_8UC1 an foreground pixel must be WHITE so you should invert your image (255-imageA) then it should work!

Comment: You are right I inverted it and now this image behaves like expected. However others don't. Rectangles that are clearly inside others are drawn.

Comment: can you post `imageA` of one of those samples?

Comment: @TomTom... try `Imgproc.RETR_LIST` instead of `Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL.`

Comment: @Micka Sure I edited the post and added an example. Note that is not the original image size. About a 7th of it.

Comment: as you can see, the contours aren't well defined in your input image. There should be nonzero-elements on the whole contour. If a contour in your input is split, `findContours` will find one (edge-like) contour for each contour-piece and hierarchy wont work as you expect, because there is no connected outer-contour.

Comment: and if you mean that there are rectangles in different rectangles that's not a hierarchy fault but a displaying fault since you draw rectangles instead of contours, so within a thin contour (that looks like a line) there isnt anything else, but in the bounding rectangle of that contour, there might be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input image isnt good enought o extract the contours you want to have.

Your input contours are these (part of your image):

[image]

each color is a single contour (and some of the white ones)

For the red contour I've drawn the bounding rectangle which is the same method that you used to display the contours. All the other colored contours aren't inside of the red contour, but just inside of the bounding rectangle, that's why they are found even though you selected to only find the outer contours.

What you really want is something like this:

[image]

but to get that result, your input image must have that lines of the ellipse connected, too!!

For your input image it will be very hard to extract those lines, without getting lines of the ground too, but an easy approach could be to use a couple of dilation operations followed by the same number of erosion operations on your input image, before extracting contours. This won't be stable for all setting though ;)

Comment: Let's see if I can find a stable solution then :)